# Error in aggregate time series using highfrequency package in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series set of data in CSV format. I used the command below to convert my data to xts:

```
> m_xts<-as.xts(m,order.by=as.POSIXct(month[, 1], format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'))
> head(m_xts)
                      [,1]
2006-01-01 16:52:24 1.1845
2006-01-01 16:52:36 1.1841
2006-01-01 21:52:45 1.1839
2006-01-01 22:22:19 1.1840
2006-01-01 22:22:20 1.1840
2006-01-01 22:53:13 1.1839
```

I would like to aggregate my time series to lower frequency, for example: to weekly, daily, hourly, etc., so I use the following commands:

```
mh <- aggregatets(m_xts, FUN="previoustick",on="hours",k=1)
m30m <- aggregatets(m_xts, FUN="previoustick",on="minutes",k=30)
md <- aggregatets(m_xts, FUN="previoustick",on="days",k=1)
mw <- aggregatets(m_xts, FUN="previoustick",on="weeks",k=1)
```

They worked well on hourly and 30 minutes frequencies but not on lower frequencies. The following error showed up for daily and weekly:

```
Error in paste(k, tby, sep = " ") : object 'tby' not found
```

I wonder if I did something wrong that make the commands not working on daily and weekly frequencies.

Comment: `aggregatets` is your custom function?

Comment: Looks like you haven't defined `tby` in your workspace.

Comment: @AndriyT: `aggregatets` is a function in `highfrequency` package

Comment: @kristang: thanks kristang, I use `aggregatets` function in `highfrequency` package and it works fine at higher frequency such as hourly and minutes but not at daily and weekly. I tried `help(aggregatets)` to figure how the function works but couldn't figure out why the problem occurs at lower frequency and what `tby` object is.

Comment: If you are in RStudio you can see the source of a function by holding ctrl and clicking on it, or by having the cursor on the function and choosing "Code" in the menu, and "Go to Function Definition". In there you can find the spot where `tby` is defined. In my testing I run in to the same issue, but I am afraid I can't really figure out the correction. `tby` is used to create an index `allindex` that is used as the argument to `order.by` in an `xts`

Comment: Adding `dropna = TRUE` to `aggregatets` means the function will define `tby`, as there is an if-statement based on `dropna` wherein it gets defined. Maybe there is a misplaced bracket in the function at that point?

Comment: thanks @kristang, that helps alot!!!

Comment: Be aware that this of course means you are dropping intervals that are empty. From `aggregatets`:
"dropna - boolean, which determines whether empty intervals should be dropped. By default, an NA is returned in case an interval is empty, except when the user opts for previous tick aggregation, by setting FUN="previoustick" (default)."